# Best Practices in Flutter/Dart and Clean Architecture (maintaining separation of concerns between data, domain and presentation layers)

Tags: flutter, dart, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I'm a backend developer with background of Java and Python. I've started with Flutter 3 months ago. I find Dart an easy language to learn and fun to write code in. Google did a good job there.

What is challenging for me is figuring out **best practices** when working with flutter. The official documentation ([docs.flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev)) is good and it's also interesting to look at the Dart code powering the framework. But I haven't seen a resource that goes over best practices for design/architecture of a Flutter application.
In particular, I'm interested in how to maintain **separation of concerns** between Database , Domain and Presentation layers.

I'm using Firebase Store for my (realtime) database. The API provides the data in the form of a JSON object (Map). This is fine, but I want to translate this into my own domain model instances (for data validation, enrichment and enforcing other business rules). What I don't know is how to bridge the gap between database and UI (Widgets). I want to keep a **Clean Architecture**, and would like to learn how to do this correctly. I should also add that I don't have prior experience with **Asynchronous** code, which seems to be an important skill to gain.

I've experimented in using **InheritedWidgets** to try and expose my data to the UI/Presentation layer as model instances, without the UI knowing about the specifics of the database, but ran into difficulties because I don't understand the Flutter framework and Dart async programming very well. I also know there are frameworks like [Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) that are supposed to solve data/state management issues. But as much as possible I want to stick to the basics before I start using more elaborate and heavier tools.

What recommended resources are out there that I'm missing, that could help me become a better Dart/Flutter developer?

Comment: I found answers to all your questions and more from this [site](https://codewithandrea.com). Everything from flutter clean architecture with riverpod to more advanced topics.

Comment: Here is a book that might help:

https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/managing-state-in/9781801070775/